# Detect jump using a UITableViewIndex

Tags: iphone

How do you know that you scrolled using the UITableViewIndex ?

I have some basic info to show on my cells, and when I jump/scroll I need to retrieve info about thoses cells by a request for a group(page) of items.

So in order to request only thoses I've stopped to, I need a way to know that I've stopped scrolling (I used scrollViewDidEndDecelerating) but with the UITableViewIndex we ca just jump to another index or scroll though them.

Answer (score 0):

The only feedback that you get is in the `UITAbleViewDelegate` protocol - none of these report that the table view has scrolled.

However, you will get calls to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` calls to your data source - this will tell you that the table view has moved enough to want a new cell.

Also, you have the `visibleCells` property of the `UITableView` itself to see where you are in the table?

It might help if you put more detail into your question - why do you need to know that a scroll has happened?

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView inherits from UIScrollView so you can also implement the UIScrollViewDelegate methods such as scrollViewDidScroll.  When the table view scrolls, these will be called.

However, if you explain why you need to know whether the table view has scrolled, there might be a better answer.

**Edit:**
From your updated question, it's still not totally clear whether you need the scrollview delegate methods.

If you just need to update the contents of the cells themselves, put that in cellForRowAtIndexPath and the table view will automatically call it when the cell comes into view.

If you need to update something outside the table view, you might still be able to do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath or you can handle scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and then use the table view's visibleCells or indexPathsForVisibleRows methods to get the list of cells currently visible.

Comment: You say "UITableViewIndex" so what I think you mean is you have an indexed table view (with the A-Z index on the right) and you want to know when the user has touched that.  If you implement cellForRowAtIndexPath properly, the data should appear properly regardless of how the user gets to the section.

Comment: but i have some "fake" info that are used until it is updated by a remote call that is done for a batch of articles in one call

Comment: You could have some BOOL flag indicating whether the info is fake/real.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath, show "Loading..." if fake else show the real info.  When the remote call is done, it should update the table view's data source and set the flag to "real" and then call [tableView reloadData] which will automatically call cellForRowAtIndexPath again.  You could also call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths or reloadSections if you don't want/need to reload the whole table.